# Numpy filter using condition on each element

Tags: python, numpy

I have a filter expression as follows:

`feasible_agents = filter(lambda agent: agent >= cost[task, agent], agents)`

where `agents` is a python list.

Now, to get speedup, I am trying to implement this using numpy.

What would be the equivalent using numpy?

I know that this works:

```
threshold = 5.0
feasible_agents = np_agents[np_agents > threshold]
```

where `np_agents` is the numpy equivalent of `agents`.

However, I want threshold to be a function of each element in the numpy array.

Comment: "I want threshold to be a function of each element in the numpy array." Please explain.

Comment: As you can see from the first expression using lambda, the threshold is the ```cost``` value that is obtained by lookup in the cost table using each element of the ```agents``` list as key. ```task``` is a constant here. i.e. the threshold is not fixed, but will vary for every element ```agent``` in the numpy array ```np_agents```.

Comment: Difficult to vectorize a solution involving a dictionary. Maybe provide a [mcve]. If the keys to your dict are integers, something may be possible here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you don't provide an example data, use toy data:

```
# Cost of agents represented by indices of cost, we have agents 0, 1, 2, 3
cost = np.array([4,5,6,2])
# Agents to consider 
np_agents = np.array([0,1,3])
# threshold for each agent. Calculate different thresholds for different agents. Use array of indexes np_agents into cost array.
thresholds = cost[np_agents] # np.array([4,5,2])
feasible_agents = np_agents[np_agents > thresholds] # np.array([3])
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use [numpy.extract](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.extract.html):

```
>>> nparr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
>>> nparreven = np.extract(nparr % 2 == 0, nparr)
```

or [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
>>> nparr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
>>> nparreven = nparr[np.where(nparr % 2 == 0)]
```