# Using slice/mask instead of a for-loop to find items in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
p= np.array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
   [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
   [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
   [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]])
```

I have the above array and need to find the items that are divisible by 2 and 3 without converting it to a flat array using for-loops and then slicing/masking.

I was able to figure out the for-loops part and am running into some issues with the slicing/masking part.

```
# we know that 6, 12 and 18 are divisible by 2 and 3
# therefore we can use slicing to pull those numbers out of the array

print(p[1:2,0:1]) # slice array to return 6
print(p[2:3,1:2]) # slice array to return 12
print(p[3:4,2:3]) # slice array to return 18

m=np.ma.masked_where(((p[:, :]%2==0)&(p[:, :]%3==0)),p)
print(m)

mask=np.logical_and(p%2==0,p%3==0)
print(mask)
```

Is there a more efficient way of slicing the array to find 6, 12 and 18? Also, is there a way to make either of the two mask functions output just 6, 12, and 18? The first one shows the inverse of what I want while the other returns a Boolean answer.

Comment: Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52380972/numpy-filter-using-condition-on-each-element)

Answer (score 1):

You nearly had it!

```
mask=np.logical_and(p%2==0,p%3==0)
```

gives you `True` where `p % 2 == 0 and p % 3 == 0`.

```
mask = array([[False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False]])
```

From this, you can get the values of `p` where `mask` is `True` by simply

```
p[mask]
```

Which gives the output:

```
array([ 6, 12, 18])
```

Comment: Whoa thanks Pranav. I have tried alot of different things to do that but apparently not that one. I appreciate the help.

Comment: If this provided your preferred answer to your question, please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply do `p[p%6==0]` ?

```
import numpy as np

p= np.array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
   [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
   [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
   [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]])

p[p%6==0] # [ 6 12 18]
```

Comment: Good question but the assignment says 3 and 2. But I think this would be acceptable. :D

Comment: I hope it is.  Leveraging basic math should be encouraged as it always gives better/faster algorithms.